# Cordova/Phonegap dialogs/notifications (native dialogs) doesn't work

Tags: cordova, phonegap-plugins

I'm trying to start a new application development with **Cordova/Phonegap usage**

Cordova version: **3.3.1-0.4.2**

I've successfully managed to create cordova project using:

```
cordova create projectx pl.projectx ProjectX
cd projectx
cordova platform add ios
```

CLI created dir for iOS project, that contains files and XCode project file.
After building and running the project, I can see on the screen 'Device is running'

Index page receives deviceReady event (tried with alert in browser - it works)

With CLI I added native notifications plugin:

```
cordova plugin add org.apache.cordova.dialogs
```

In config.xml I can see:

```
<feature name="Notification">
    <param name="ios-package" value="CDVNotification" />
</feature>
```

I've checked **Targets->Build Phases->Compile Sources** and there is **CDVNotifaction.m** file added.

When trying to use

```
navigator.notification.alert(...)
```

it doesn't work (even added callback function as one said it might be a problem with ios platform).

Do you have any idea where I am wrong ?

Answer (score 0):

Run it and watch console.  If you get a "Refused to execute inline event handler" type message then add 'unsafe-inline' to your default source in the content security policy of your config.xml file.

```
<meta http-equiv="Content-Security-Policy" content="default-src 'self'   
data: gap: https://ssl.gstatic.com 'unsafe-inline' 
'unsafe-eval'; style-src 'self'; media-src *;">
```

Details on the policies are available at https://developer.chrome.com/extensions/contentSecurityPolicy .

Hope this helps.  Healy in Tampa.